# How do I use a shell builtin command rather than the system command?

Tags: freebsd, echo, command-line-interface

I'm specifically asking about FreeBSD.  I am using the default /bin/csh as my shell.  There is a binary version of echo at /bin/echo, and there is an echo command built into the shell.  The system command lacks the ability to use System V style backslashed escape characters such as:

```
\n
\t
```

I want to be able to prefer the shell's builtin rather than the system command without making a temporary change to path or deleting /bin/echo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, your shell will prefer its own builtin over any external program.  One notable gotcha in regards to this is when you've defined an alias for the command.